# INSERT INTO, but retain blank columns?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

In a stored procedure I'm creating...

```
    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..##SUBOSummary') IS NOT NULL
        /*Then it exists*/
        DROP TABLE ##SUBOSummary
    CREATE TABLE  ##SUBOSummary
        (
            --RowID int not null identity(1,1) primary key,
            RowNum int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
            Dept nvarchar(25) NOT NULL,
            Last24 int,
            WTD int,
            MoTD int,
            YTD int
        )
```

I then want to add a series of data from another view, and I'll then fill the rest of the data rows in seperately:

```
INSERT INTO ##SUBOSummary SELECT DISTINCT vw_EmployeeDepartment.Dept FROM vw_EmployeeDepartment
```

I'm getting the following error:

> Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.

I'm hazarding a guess that this is because I'm only populating a single field by the insert statement.

Is there a better way to acheive this?

Comment: you need select all value of your temp table in select, you are selecting only dept value

Comment: @HasanFathi The OP is inserting into their temporary table, they aren't selecting from it at all.

Comment: Always, always explicitly set the column list of the table you want to insert to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error, in truth, is quite clear here:

> Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.

In your `INSERT` statement you're implying you want to insert values into all the columns (as you're not specifying which one), yet you're only supplying one column in your `SELECT`, so where does that value go? SQL Server has no idea.

You need to supply your column(s) in your `INSERT` clause:

```
INSERT INTO ##SUBOSummary (Dept)
SELECT DISTINCT vw_EmployeeDepartment.Dept
FROM vw_EmployeeDepartment;
```

On a different note, however, don't use a Global Temporary Table, they often perform very poorly.

Comment: Thanks Larnu, for both.  What would you suggest as an alternative to the temp table?

Comment: use a static table, then drop it when it becomes obsolete.

Comment: @B3S beat me to the punch. Global Temporary tables tend to actually be worse than Temporary tables. If the idea is that you want the object to persist between batches and connections, then definitely create the object in a "normal" database. If it's something you use use frequently, then you might be better creating it (perhaps putting some indexes on it, if needed), and simply using `TRUNCATE` on it when you're done.

Comment: "they often poorly very poorly."... I'm guessing this is a remark about performance :-)